# PowerBI Matrix Visual sorting

Tags: powerbi

I created a Matrix visualization.

Rows: item number

Columns: year-month

Values: Stock value, an stock value2

How can I sort the stock value2? 
The Little triangle is not there to do it.

Once i remove the month columns i can sort them but it is not the solution what im looking for. I want to show the top 0-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Matrix Vis you cannot sort on the column (in your case year-month), this has all to do with the fact that this is dynamic created. When you change your row values of year-month, you have more or less columns. For this reason it is not possible to select the column for sorting.

You could think about creating a cross-table based on your data and then use the table visual.